# sorting txt file into a vector in c++

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

hey guys i have a c++ question.

im trying to write a program that will open and read a txt file of numbers and names such as:
"9 john 3 jane 7 tom 2 sam 6 tom 1 nicole 5 tom 4 jane 8 ben"

once ive read the file i need to place the names in a vector in order of the numbers assigned to them. so when i print the vector it should be in this order:

nicole

sam

jane

jane

tom

tom

tom

ben

john

then i need to take the sorted vector and place the names in a new file with the number of times each name occurs. so when i print this new file the output should look like this:

nicole       1

sam       1

jane       2

tom       3

ben       1

john       1

so far this is my code:
(ignore the count_names function as i was only using it to test my output)
(i will need to do a recursive function later on so ignore any #include that i do not need at the moment)

```
using namespace std;

void fill_vector ( vector<string> &v );

void print_vector ( vector<string> v );

int count_names ( vector<string> v );

int main()
{

    vector<string> v;
    string s;

    fill_vector(v);

    int num_names;
    num_strings = count_strings(v)/2;
    cout << "number of names " << num_names << endl;

    print_vector(v);

    return 0;

}

void fill_vector ( vector<string> &v )
{
    string s;

    ifstream fin;
    string input = "toy_names.txt";
    fin.open ( input.c_str() );
    fin >> s;

    while ( !fin.eof() )
    {
        v.push_back ( s );
        fin >> s;
    }
}

void print_vector ( vector<string> v )
{

    for ( int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++ )
        cout << v[i] << endl;
}

int count_names ( vector<string> v )
{

    int counter = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++ )
    {
        counter++;
    }

    return counter;
}
```

so as of right now this is my output:

9

john

3

jane

7

tom

2

sam

6

tom

1

nicole

5

tom

4

jane

8

ben

so i need help getting them into the proper order (the names in order of the number before them) and then writing them to the new txt file
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>>` and just use `std::sort(<yourvec>.begin(), <yourvec>.end()` to sort your members.
To create a `std::pair<int, std::string>`, call the constructor with your number, and the name linked with it.

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers are unique, put the numbers and names into a [`std::map<int, std::string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map). While you are at it, count the occurrences of each name in a [`std::map<std::string, unsigned int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).